# How can I select rows in reverse order in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I select rows in reverse order in MySQL?

For example, I have a table with 12 rows (fields: id,location), I want to select the 4th row before a row with id = 6. I.e., the wanted row will have id = 'not necessarily 2', but there is a condition - where table.location='some_location'.

What should the content of request to MySQL be like?

---

Here is a solution!

Some example (I checked [drodil's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582393/how-can-i-select-rows-in-reverse-order-in-mysql/9582677#9582677)):

```sql
mysql> select * from subscrs where id < 100000 order by id desc limit 4;
+-------+--------+-----------+-------+
| uid   | subscr | event     | id    |
+-------+--------+-----------+-------+
|  5307 |   5123 | feed_news | 99999 |
| 25985 |   5211 | feed_news | 99998 |
| 15123 |    130 | feed_news | 99997 |
| 28368 |  19497 | feed_news | 99996 |
+-------+--------+-----------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve by selecting a row with an ID 4 below the ID that was supplied.

Please provide some more details because I think it is likely that there is a better suited solution to your problem.

Comment: Can you clarify your question, perhaps by including some sample data and how you want it to be ordered? At the moment, I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: What happens if your id is auto incrementing and someone has removed the row id 2 in your case, what should it do then? What happens if the provided id is 2, so that four rows prior would have id -1 (not existing)?

Comment: I need 'reverse order of search'.

Comment: there is no order of search in SQL - can you show us some exaple data, what is the input and what is the desired output of the SQL please?

Comment: I need 'reverse order of innoDB's search' in request like this: select uid from sessions where location='cafe' and uid=((select uid from sessions where location='cafe' and uid=6 limit 1) - (#"4 rows with location 'cafe' before uid=6")); . And I can use only one select by request (nosql by handlersocket).

Comment: succeeded! succeeded! succeeded!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Or you could do it without caring about the deleted results. Just get the fourth before the given id (6) by:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE id < 6 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4,1
```

Answer (score 3):

Please add `ORDER BY id DESC` in the last of your query to fetch the data from last to first.

**OR**

For assenting order, you can simply add `ORDER BY id ASC`.

Answer (score 2):

The 4th row before a given row, or the 4th ID before a given ID?  There may be IDs missing due to deleted records (ie.. IDs 101, 102, 104, 105, 111, ...)... If you just want an ID 4 less than some other ID for whatever reason (I would agree more info should be given here, as there's likely a better solution!) then you can simply do

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE ID=6-4
```

You can expand on that if you want the ID 4 less than the ID of the row containing a specific location with

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE ID = (SELECT ID FROM SomeTable WHERE Location='Germany')-4
```

But again, please share some sample data and what you're trying to achieve/why you're planning to do it this way - this isn't a logical solution.  If ID 2 had been deleted, or if your Location field does not contain unique data - then this will break.  There must be a better design for what you're trying to do, but you need to provide more details for that.

Comment: I posted a similar answer at first, but then removed it again becuase this would break in several cases. See my comment to the question.

Comment: Yeah, I certainly agree - the user needs to have tight control over the DB for this to work, and even then it's a completely terrible way of doing/approaching things.  But so far as I can understand the question with what's provided this seems to be what he's asking for.

Comment: I expanded the answer a bit.  This will "work" so to speak, but what you're asking for is a bad way of approaching things.  Would love to help more, but need more info.

Comment: maxx233. I have found the solution (by man, named drodil). Drodil, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If my mind-reading is still working, you probably need something like this:

```
select t1.location, t2.location
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 on t2.id = t1.id - 4
where t1.location = 'some_location'
```