# Mysql + PHP, ASC after that DESC every 5 data?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `t1`. My query

```
$mdata = DB::fetch_all("SELECT * FROM t1 ORDER BY id ASC"); //template language from Discuz!
```

My data output will like below, every 5 row change new line (using CSS width: 20%)

```
+----------------+
| 1  2  3  4  5  |
| 6  7  8  9  10 |
| 11 12 13 14 15 |
+----------------+
```

But how I reorder data as below?

```
+----------------+
| 11 12 13 14 15 |
| 6  7  8  9  10 |
| 1  2  3  4  5  |
+----------------+
```

My template language `DB::` was not allow select in select `SELECT * FROM (SELECT *)...`, or maybe can reorder using PHP?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I select rows in reverse order (mysql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582393/how-can-i-select-rows-in-reverse-order-mysql)

Comment: hi, I want fetch_all data, and reorder, the link you provide is select after certain condition, no match what I need, thank you!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk) to split your data into chunks of 5, then output the contents of the chunked array in reverse order. For example:

```
$mdata = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15);

$rows = array_chunk($mdata, 5);
for ($i = count($rows) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    echo implode(' ', $rows[$i]) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
11 12 13 14 15
6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Khmcl)

Comment: Hi, after I using fetch all, the array will like `$mdata = array(0=>array('id'=>1,'title'=>'aa'),1=>array('id'=>2,'title'=>'bb'));` so how to edit in your `for()`? thanks

Comment: What values do you want to output?

Comment: You should be able to use the same code you currently use to output each value of `$mdata`